# Merge Two Data Frames based on Matching Row Criteria and Shared Columns

Tags: r, merge

So here are the data sets I'm working with:

Data1:

```
ID   Grade   Year
1    A       2000
2    B       2001
3    C       2002
```

Data2:

```
ID   NewGrade Year
1    B        2000
2    C        2001
```

I want to merge the values from "NewGrade" in Data2 into a new column in Data1 or into a brand new Data frame "NewData". The output will look like this:

```
ID   Grade   Year   NewGrade
1    A       2000   B
2    B       2001   C
3    C       2002   NA
```

The purpose of this to show that new criteria was established for grading and there was a change from what the first value for "Grade" was which is signaled by the new value in "NewGrade." To avoid duplication, I want to merge the NewGrades based on the shared columns in both data frames "ID" and "Year." If there is no NewGrade like for ID# 3, it will return a null value.

I tried the following but it broke Rstudio:

```
newData <- merge(Data1, Data2, col=c("ID", "Year"), x.all=T)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `merge` should look like this

```
newData = merge(Data1, Data2, by = c("ID", "Year"), all.x = TRUE)
```

There are no `col` or `x.all` arguments to `merge`.